# Internet Explorer font/text turning into colored squares?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-8

My boss is complaining because a web page won't render in his browser correctly...It works on every computer/browser except his so I told him it appears to be an issue with the font on his computer and to reinstall it.

It's really odd because the font is set to "Arial, sans-serif";

This is the screenshot he sent me:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before and happen to know what causes it?

Comment: Could you include a link or CSS and HTML code

Comment: I would agree it's a font loading issue on his machine.

Comment: It's looks like the Pc has not installed the font. Weird case, Arial is a system/web-safe font. Ask the owner of the machine to check the font in the fond folder, and in case, reinstall the font.

Comment: Some are listed as `verdana` (all lowercase) and are being overwritten with the Arial font. Clearing out duplicates wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Agree with you: i've got a quick check on dev tools in IE8, and first of all i would suggest to clean up the code, and maybe check the typo of the font name.